# how to get http "GET" argument in binary format in flask?

Tags: python, http, flask, bittorrent

I'm trying to write a bittorrent tracker. The tracker protocol encode a binary hex into the http "GET" parameters. It looks like something in the following:

```
http://localhost:5000/announce?info_hash=%C5O%94%1b%1a9%86%86%12B%D7U%D0%ACF%E9%FA%3c%5d2
```

If I use request.args, it will try to decode the "info_hash" into a string, which will not work because the info_hash should just be some raw binary sequence which can't be represented by any string encoding.

So is there anything I could use to extract the result in bytes without rolling my own parser?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there does not seem to be a really simple way of doing this with the standard library.

The way to go is to take the raw query string via `request.query_string` and parse it. The problem is that Python standard library functions all assume that that the values are also Unicode, which is of course not true for Bittorrent trackers as you have pointed out.

The thing is that the standard library has all of the required functionality, namely the function `parse_qs` from `urllib.parse` to implement with minor modifications:

```
def parse_qs_to_bytes(qs, keep_blank_values=False, strict_parsing=False,
             max_num_fields=None):
  
    parsed_result = {}
    pairs = parse_qsl(qs, keep_blank_values, strict_parsing,
                      max_num_fields=max_num_fields)
    for name, value in pairs:
        if name in parsed_result:
            parsed_result[name].append(value)
        else:
            parsed_result[name] = [value]
    return parsed_result


def parse_qsl(qs, keep_blank_values=False, strict_parsing=False,
              max_num_fields=None):
    if max_num_fields is not None:
        num_fields = 1 + qs.count('&') + qs.count(';')
        if max_num_fields < num_fields:
            raise ValueError('Max number of fields exceeded')
    pairs = [s2 for s1 in qs.split('&') for s2 in s1.split(';')]
    r = []
    for name_value in pairs:
        if not name_value and not strict_parsing:
            continue
        nv = name_value.split('=', 1)
        if len(nv) != 2:
            if strict_parsing:
                raise ValueError("bad query field: %r" % (name_value,))
            # Handle case of a control-name with no equal sign
            if keep_blank_values:
                nv.append('')
            else:
                continue
        if len(nv[1]) or keep_blank_values:
            name = nv[0].replace('+', ' ')
            name = unquote(name)
            value = nv[1].replace('+', ' ')
            value = unquote_to_bytes(value) # changed line from original to prevent coercing into unicode
            r.append((name, value))
    return r
```

So, you should be able to call `parse_qs_bytes_to_bytes(request.query_string.decode())`